# How do I locate a third party page represented as a slug in my WordPress website?

Tags: pages, wp-admin, slug

how do I determine where a WordPress page is located in the admin panel when the page has been built via a third party plugin and has been uploaded to a directory that is just represented by a slug? It goes to example.com/here/ but how do I find out where the '/here/' portion is represented as a WordPress page or file in the admin panel? The page was created using a third party page creator on https://weblimitless.com/ and I can't find the page when searching the pages panel in my WordPress admin panel.

Comment: Since it was created by a third-party plugin as an actual file, you cannot find it in wp-admin by default. WordPress only stores its own known Pages as Pages. It has no way to know about content outside of WordPress. That said, you may be able to add a dashboard widget or something like that to display all of these third-party pages. I'd ask the third party if this is possible with their own code before trying to custom code it.

Comment: would there be a way I could access the redirect information from WordPress admin panel? like does WordPress have an option where I can upload a html/php file and allow me to select the redirect slug? I'm wondering because I currently don't have access to the web hosting account at the moment.

Comment: WP doesn't have a way to do this. Again I'd ask the third party because they may have a plugin you can install through wp-admin, without hosting access, that will show this information. Or, you could install a plugin that lets you leave notes on your dashboard - there are several available - and you could track them manually.